# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :java

Tags: android

How can I add module dependency in android studio?

Project Structure
[image]

[image]

[image]

When I add module dependencies there is no module to add?

[image]

My android studio version : 3.6.1

[image]

[image]

build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.thu"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation project(path: ':java')  //i edited here try this


}
```

error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
not resolve project :java.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Fastest way: just edit the build.gradle files

Comment: Where can I edit the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add the Module .first you should add with this way :
[image]
after adding module you can add your dependency

Comment: how can i add the module in my dependency?

Comment: in my answer is a image link.

Comment: first right click on app--->new -----> Module . send me an image.

Comment: i add my module but how can i add my module in dependency

Comment: go build.gradle(module app )and in dependencies add with this structure : implementation project(path: ' :your file name')

Comment: delete this line : implementation project(":java")

Comment: where can i add this  implementation project(path: ' :your file name')?

Comment: and after that add this line : implementation project(path: ' : your Module  name')

Comment: my module name is java . so , i add java like this implementation project(":java").

Comment: did you try again? what happened?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133565/when-i-import-opencv-with-android-studio-it-not-done

Comment: i edited again (remove path). copy again and sync. if again same error occured , rename the  file name . maybe "java" is not suitable name . @PradeepSimba