# when I import opencv with android studio it not done

Tags: android, opencv

when I import opencv with android studio it not done.

Android studio version 3.6.2

[image]

opencv version

[image]

when i import opencv module

[image]

build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.thu"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation project(path: ':java')  


}
```

Error :

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
not resolve project :java.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

How can I solve this?

Why this error comes how can i solve this error?

what mistake i did in this?

I followed this youtube [tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzuwrYgOnDQ&t=650s)

My another [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117883/error-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not)

Comment: it could be found in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas

Comment: But , it not done.